# MongoDB with mongoose or SQL

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm a bit new to mongoDB and I'm trying to figure out if I should use MongoDB or to use the familiar SQL.

At first I really wanted to use MongoDB but it's going really slow, and I'm having a hard time how to design my DB and queries.

For instance:
**SQL**

Let's say I have these tables:

```
User Table (Id, Name)

Group (Id, Name)

GroupInvites (UserId, GroupId, Status[A - active, I - invited])
```

And if I wanted to know if a player has and group invitations, it would be pretty easy the SELECT and UPDATE from the GroupInvites table.

**MongoDB**

But in MongoDB the GroupInvites is redundant, because we can have the Status in the group scheme.

```
const BetGroupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    users: [{
        userId: {
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users',
            required: true
        },
        userStatus: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
     }]
})
```

But now, if I wanted to SELECT only the groups that a specific user has an invite for, it would be much harder -

```
Group.find({
    "users.userId": req.user._id,
    "users.userStatus": "I"
})
```

The result of this would give a all group that have the UserID and all the groups that have UserStatus = 'I'.

And also I can't find a quick way to update the DB directly, If I wanted to update a specific user status to 'A'.

Maybe I got this wrong and someone can show me a good way to implement it in MongoDB or you think it would be better to go with SQL.

Comment: Just because you can nest the users within group does not mean you have to. In your case, I would still have three distinct collections (i.e. tables). You can do `$lookup` queries (i.e. joins) in MongoDB, too.

Comment: @str If I keep 3 collections what is the advantage using mongoDB if I create a relational DB like SQL.

Comment: @str sure you can do but since mongodb allow you to embedded your document so that you get the data in one shot , lookup queries are costly compare to single collection query. at the end it depends how you want  to design your sachemas.

Comment: @OreT Nesting is not the only difference to SQL. NoSQL database engines have advantages and disadvantages so I cannot tell you whether MongoDB is better in your case. Nesting might be great for some functionalities, but in your case it might also make things harder. See [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand as a beginner it becomes hard to do even a simple query well,  if I would be at your place, I will do the query like this in a following way

**1. Find query for a document nested in an array:**

```
 Group.find({users: {$elemMatch: {userId:req.user._id, userStatus:"I"}}})
```

**2. Update query for a document nested in an array:**

```
Group.update( { "name": "John","users.userId" : req.user._id }, 
              { "$set": { "users.$.userStatus": "A" } } )
```

Comment: Can you explain the $ between the dot notation?

Comment: @OreT  sure, its a positional "$" operator , for example if one of the field in your schema is an array of objects , in your case it is "users" field, then in order to point out and update a specific one object , you will need to use "$" operator in your query.

Comment: Isn't the update function suppose to be on the result of the of the find? Or am I missing something? Because in this way the update will occur on all Group's that have a user named John OR the UserId.

Comment: @OreT Did that solve your problem or doubt? , let me know if  you are still facing issues. Thanks

Comment: since userId is unique, so update query will update a individual object field at a time. for example the query group.update( { "name": "John","users.userId" : req.user._id }, { "$set": { "users.$.userStatus": "A" } } ) means update the userstatus of a user for which userid is 'bla bla' and  name is 'John'.